# How to make a shell script wait for another with out using sleep

Tags: shell

I want to know how to make a shell script wait till other script finishes its execution with out the help of sleep command.

suppose i have scripts run.sh and kill.sh, where run.sh will make all the processes up(means to start running the image on the box) whereas kill.sh contains just the kill commands to kill all the running processes.

Whenever i have run the run.sh, it will make all the processes up and it will end. Then what happens here is all the running processes becoming orphan(handled by init). Whenever we run kill.sh, some of the processes are becoming zombies.

**Means, Orphan processes becoming zombies.**

To avoid this, i want to make the run.sh wait till the end of kill.sh script.

So, How to make a shell script wait for another script ? Please provide the comments.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: care to elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait to let the first script finish without giving an explicit sleep.

```
#!/bin/bash

./first_script.sh
wait
./second_script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't want to use any commands on the shell prompt, anything should be changed inside those scripts only.

Comment: You can create a script as shown in my answer which calls the first script & waits till it finishes and then calls the second script.

Comment: Thanks, 
I do not want to create a new script also.Any changes should go with in those 2 scripts only. I have edited my question.please check once again

Comment: Still there's no clarity in your question.